# How to correctly send json with httpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a `httpWebRequest` object.

It is initialised like this:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myURL.com"); // This is actually my company URL I can't show
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
```

Then I want to send to this URL json datas. After tries, I figured I do it wrong, but I don't get what it is... Here is where I send it datas:

```
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            List<string> datas = new List<string>();
            datas.Add("1");


            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datas);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to catch the URL I'm sending? I tried Fiddler, but I don't see my request.

Also this code works with a chrome console:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                'url': 'http://myURL.com',  
                'type': 'POST',
                'data': {data:[7]},
                'success': function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You're sending to `"http://myURL"`, the URL you passed to the Create function. Maybe you mean "the content"? This article may be of help to trace the problem: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/05/05/using-network-tracing-to-debug-system-net-based-issues/

Comment: the URL is actually not this one and if fine, I tested it. I will edit my code

Comment: Yes, I understand that's not your real URL, what I meant is you will call to anything you passed to the `Create` function.

Comment: exactly... so this URL should be fine, the one I use?

Comment: I can't know if it's fine, if that is the URL the service provider gave you it should, maybe worth to try to call to the URL from a browser, or if this is a json post there are some plugins for Chrome/Firefox to test these calls.

Comment: Don't flush and close your stream before invoking the service.

Comment: I do it in chrome, and it works fine. I will add it to my description

Comment: @Theo when should I flush it?

Comment: @Gusman I added the code I do in chrome console which works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you use at Chrome it is denoted your data structure is not correct.

First, you need a class to store the data, lets call it DataHolder:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public int[] data { get; set; }
}
```

So now you need to fill it:

```
var newData = new DataHolder{ data = new int[] { 1 } };
```

And now you can serialize it and it should work:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newData);
```

EDIT: as a note, in a previous question you posted you tried to send `"{ data: [1] }"` which is incorrect, it should be `"{ \"data\": [1] }"` but better stick to a class with the correct structure and let the serializer deal with those implementation details.